# DynamoDB Data migration with transformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, etl

I need to migrate data from Table A to Table B.

I need to move every item in Table A, with the largest rangeKey to Table B.

That is, each item with just the largest version, will reside in Table B.

I've thought of scanning through Table A, and then doing a conditional write on table B(write if only the item exists with a smaller rangeKey value for that item, or if the item doesn't exist at all), but this seems unfeasible as this takes too long(Table A is HUGE).

Is there a better way to do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done more efficiently but first you will need to obtain all values of partition key that you are storing in your table.

If you don't already know the values, then you will need to `scan` the table and extract these unique values, you can use `ProjectionExpression` to return just a partition key values.

example in Python

```
def get_partition_key_values():
    response = dynamodb_client.scan(
        TableName=SOURCE_TABLE,
        ProjectionExpression=PARTITION_KEY_NAME
    )

    values = [item[PARTITION_KEY_NAME][PARTITION_KEY_TYPE]
              for item in response['Items']]
    return set(values)
```

Now that you have partition key values, you can simply query table for each unique partition key in a loop, sort the result using `ScanIndexForward` attribute set to `False` and `Limit` the amount of returned values to `1` which will return one item per partition key with the 'biggest' sort key.

As you are looping through the keys and obtaining the desired items, you can put them into destination table one by one

```
def copy_items(partition_keys):
    for key in partition_keys:
        item = dynamodb_client.query(
            TableName=SOURCE_TABLE,
            KeyConditionExpression='#pid = :pid',
            ExpressionAttributeNames={
                '#pid': PARTITION_KEY_NAME
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':pid': {
                    PARTITION_KEY_TYPE: key
                }
            },
            Limit=1,
            ScanIndexForward=False
        )['Items'][0]

        dynamodb_client.put_item(
            TableName=DESTINATION_TABLE,
            Item=item
        )
```

Here is the full code

```
import boto3

dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

SOURCE_TABLE = 'products'
DESTINATION_TABLE = 'products_copy'

PARTITION_KEY_NAME = 'product_id'
PARTITION_KEY_TYPE = 'S'


def get_partition_key_values():
    response = dynamodb_client.scan(
        TableName=SOURCE_TABLE,
        ProjectionExpression=PARTITION_KEY_NAME
    )

    values = [item[PARTITION_KEY_NAME][PARTITION_KEY_TYPE]
              for item in response['Items']]
    return set(values)


def copy_items(partition_keys):
    for key in partition_keys:
        item = dynamodb_client.query(
            TableName=SOURCE_TABLE,
            KeyConditionExpression='#pid = :pid',
            ExpressionAttributeNames={
                '#pid': PARTITION_KEY_NAME
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':pid': {
                    PARTITION_KEY_TYPE: key
                }
            },
            Limit=1,
            ScanIndexForward=False
        )['Items'][0]

        dynamodb_client.put_item(
            TableName=DESTINATION_TABLE,
            Item=item
        )


unique_partition_key_values = get_partition_key_values()

copy_items(unique_partition_key_values)
```

Just note that the above code assumes that both the source and destination table have the same primary key schema. If those two schemas differ in your case, then you will need to perform some additional transformation/mapping.

Comment: Simple code. Thanks for sharing. You might need to add failure handling conditions and does not scale well with huge records.

Comment: Ofc, in production you will need some error handling. I just didn't want to make the code too difficult to read with all the try/catch statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we did it.

> Lambda (to scan and delete old records) --> DynamoDB Stream --> Lambda
>   to Write (DO Transformation and write to new table)

If you have partitions and capacity configured dynamically, you can trigger multiple lambda to handle different partitions and delete the data accordingly.

The above is a simple approach.

You can also do it via Data Pipeline.

> Export DynamoDB Records with Data Pipeline --> S3 --> Transform With
>   Lambda and Write it to S3 --> Import with Data Pipeline

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb.html

Hope it helps.